# Fan-in with resistor?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

Should the attached diagram have a fan-in of 4 or 8?
Do resistors and resistance also count as a fan-in,
since it acts like an input as well?

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is 8, fan-in speaks to the hidden logic complexity and thus speed.  Tying inputs together does not remove those elements inside the gate (transistors).

In some synthesis engines, this cell would be optimized to a 4 input gate and then the fan-in *would* be 4.